# C++ Boost: Simple nested dictionary?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, nested

What is the simplest way to implement a nested dictionary with string keys, and string/int/dictionary values?

What I tried so far, is a weird:
    `boost::fusion::map<std::string, boost:variant<std::string, int, boost::fusion::map<std::string, boost:variant<std::string, int>>>>`

This looks like it has depth 2, and also it looks like It is definitely not going to work.
Even if it will, I'm puzzled on how to use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it like this,

```
template<int N> struct my_map {
    typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, typename my_map<N-1>::type> value_type;
    typedef std::map<std::string, value_type> type;
};
template<> struct my_map<1> {
    typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> value_type;
    typedef std::map<std::string, value_type> type;
};
```

Possibly replacing `std::map` with the `boost::fusion::map`, but maybe you are better off with a much simpler design, with (smart) pointers to chained entries that become `nullptr` when you need to terminate.

Comment: can you give a usage example for this?